# Update data on a row depending on another one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this one :

```
         Date                         Name
0  07/08/2023    LUZZO GRACA      03/08/23
1  08/08/2023                 SEPA PREDICA
2  08/08/2023    MINIPRECO FAMILY 05/08/23
3  09/08/2023    PQ. CASA DE MUS  08/08/23
```

I want to change the `Date` column to the date stored in the `Name` column. And adding `20` to the beggind of year. So the date should look like `dd/mm/yyyy`.

And if so, remove the date from the `Name` column.

So it would look like :

```
         Date                Name
0  02/08/2023         LUZZO GRACA      
1  08/08/2023        SEPA PREDICA
2  05/08/2023    MINIPRECO FAMILY
3  08/08/2023     PQ. CASA DE MUS
```

I have tried several things, but they were quite long to process, because I had to iterate 2 times over name.

```
def update_date(row):
    last_part = row["Name"].rsplit(' ', 1)[-1]
    if re.match(r'(?:[0-2]\d|3[0-2])/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:[2-9]\d)', last_part):
        print()
        return last_part[:6]+"20"+last_part[6:]
    return row["Date"]

def update_name(row):
    first_part, last_part = row["Name"].rsplit(' ', 1)
    if re.match(r'(?:[0-2]\d|3[0-2])/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:[2-9]\d)', last_part):
        return first_part.strip()
    return row["Name"]
```

And calling them like that :

```
df["Date"] = df.apply(update_date, axis=1)
df["Name"] = df.apply(update_name, axis=1)
```

It's one of my first post, I might have forget important information

Comment: How are you getting this data? I'm just thinking it might be easier to fix the problem earlier.

Comment: "02/08/2023" in the output doesn't match "03/08/23" in the input

Comment: I just realized, the title doesn't describe what you're trying to do at all. You want to update a *column* based on another one, but that's still vague. Please read [ask] for tips on that, then [edit] to clarify.

Comment: If you want to learn how to use regex with Pandas more effectively, that's covered by the user guide: [Extracting substrings](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#extracting-substrings). If you want to learn how to more efficiently iterate through a dataframe, see [cs95's answer on "How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas"](/a/55557758/4518341) (TLDR: don't, use vectorization instead).

Comment: BTW, if you're going to be working with these dates (and not just immediately dumping them into a CSV or something) then you should [parse them](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/09_timeseries.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

def fix(dt):
    date = re.findall('(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})', dt)[0]
    return date[:6] + '20' + date[6:]


pattern = '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}'
filter1 = df.Name.str.contains(pattern)
df.loc[filter1, 'Date'] = df.loc[filter1, 'Name'].map(fix)
df.loc[filter1, 'Name'] = df.loc[filter1, 'Name'].str.replace('(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})', '', regex=True)
```

You might want to strip whitespace off the Name column as the final step, I didn't bother with that step.

Answer (score 0):

Preferred approach: use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to detect the format, then [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to reformat and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to add missing values:

```
df['new'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Name'], format='%d/%m/%y',
                            exact=False, errors='coerce')
               .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
               .fillna(df['Date'])
             )
```

Output:

```
         Date                       Name         new
0  07/08/2023  LUZZO GRACA      03/08/23  03/08/2023
1  08/08/2023               SEPA PREDICA  08/08/2023
2  08/08/2023  MINIPRECO FAMILY 05/08/23  05/08/2023
3  09/08/2023  PQ. CASA DE MUS  08/08/23  08/08/2023
```

Or, to modify the column in place:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Name'], format='%d/%m/%y',
                   exact=False, errors='coerce')

m = s.notna()
df.loc[m, 'Date'] = s[m].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Output:

```
         Date                       Name
0  03/08/2023  LUZZO GRACA      03/08/23
1  08/08/2023               SEPA PREDICA
2  05/08/2023  MINIPRECO FAMILY 05/08/23
3  08/08/2023  PQ. CASA DE MUS  08/08/23
```

---

Alternatively, with a regex, [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the date, fix the year with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), fill missing values:

```
df['new'] = (df['Name']
             .str.extract(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})', expand=False)
             .str.replace(r'(..)$', r'20\1', regex=True)
             .fillna(df['Date'])
             )
```

Or, concatenate the two columns and extract the first valid date while padding the year with `20`:

```
df['new'] = (df['Name'].add(' '+df['Date'])
             .str.replace(r'^.*?(\d{2}/\d{2}/)(?:20)?(\d{2}).*$', 
                          r'\g<1>20\2', regex=True)
             )
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5a1p1e/1)